# Should lighting be done in view space or world space

Tags: glsl

I've been working on a bit of deferred rendering lately for my engine. I pretty much have it working now. However, when I move the camera a bit, I notice some subtle shading on some surfaces, but it is more apparent on other surfaces (I don't have any specular light). I've been doing my lighting calculations as well as my G-buffer rendering in view space. That makes the question arise: Should I being doing my lighting in world space? I'm pretty sure that the variations in light are coming from the normals being in view space. If it makes a difference, I am computing the view space position from a depth map. I've read that doing calculations in view space are fine, but with a bit of tinkering, I can't figure out what's wrong, and might just resort to doing it in view space. If anyone is curious here is my shader code:

Normal pass:

```
varying vec3 normal;
void main(void)
{
    gl_Position =gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*gl_Vertex;
    normal = (gl_NormalMatrix*gl_Normal)* 0.5 + 0.5;
}
```

Lighting pass:

```
uniform sampler2D positionMap;
uniform sampler2D normalMap;
uniform sampler2D albedoMap;
uniform mat4 iprojMat;
uniform int light;
uniform vec3 lightcolor;
varying vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    //get all the G-buffer information
    vec3 normal = ((texture2D(normalMap,texcoord)).rgb * 2.0 - 1.0);
    vec3 color = (texture2D(albedoMap,texcoord)).rgb;
    if (color == vec3(0,0,0))
        discard;
    float z = (texture2D(positionMap,texcoord)).r;
    float x = texcoord.x * 2.0 - 1.0;
    float y =  (1.0-texcoord.y) * 2.0 - 1.0;
    vec4 proj = vec4(x,y,z,1.0);
    proj = proj*iprojMat;
    vec3 position = proj.xyz/proj.w;

    //start making the light happen
    vec3 lightVec = (gl_LightSource[light].position.xyz - position);
    vec3 diffuselight = lightcolor * max(dot(normal,normalize(lightVec)), 0.0);
    diffuselight = clamp(diffuselight, 0.0, 1.0);
    //calculate attinuation
    float distance = length(lightVec);
    float att = 1.0/((distance*distance)+distance);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(diffuselight,1.0);
}
```

Any help or hints on this would be appreciated.

P.S. I have made a direct rendering shader as well that is also done in view space and the same kind of thing happen, but not as noticeably.

Comment: In my deferred renderer I use view space lighting because then all normals in the g-buffer are pointing towards the camera (assuming you are not rendering back-faces). That makes compressing the normals into the G-Buffer much easier. However, Cryengine does all lighting in world-space.

Comment: @Marius Any idea what would cause the small variations in the lighting then? It just seemed to me it was related to the normals.

Comment: I compress my normals to 16 bits which causes some issues on very smooth surfaces due to the quantization but usually it is not noticable. It does not cause flickering or the like.

Comment: I use world space for all of my lighting, the decision was originally made because it makes my SSAO implementation (including the computation of bent normals) quicker. There are many other post-processing effects that work more efficiently in world-space, which I suspect is why Unreal Engine 4 and CryEngine 3 also use world-space lighting. Unfortunately, world-space normals have drawbacks too, Marius did a good job mentioning most of them. For me, world-space normals were a good tradeoff for the improved post-processing efficiency. It all depends on how post-processing heavy your use-case is.

Comment: There is a very good article that discusses a lot of what I mentioned in GPU Pro 3, CryTek does a [postmortem of sorts on CryEngine 3](http://books.google.com/books?id=aG3y7WQGzmQC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147#v=onepage&q&f=false).